# Set default domain user groups on user/computer creation

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain

Currently on our domain, when a new user is created, they are automatically added to the `Domain User` group which is fine.

Also, when a new computer is added to the domain, the `Domain Admin` group is automatically added to the local `Administrators` group.

Where do I configure these settings? For example, when a new computer is added to the domain, I want to automatically add the `Domain User` group to the local computer's `Network Configuration Operators` group so that domain users can edit their IP address if they need to (when travelling on hotel networks).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Restricted Groups feature in a Group Policy to enforce membership of local groups on workstations/servers.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279301

http://www.frickelsoft.net/blog/?p=13

Comment: +1 - That's the best way to do it.

Comment: Thats sort of confusing, even though it says "Restricted Group" feature it still allows me to add domain groups to local groups?

Comment: @drpcken: Yes, the policy you create will *restrict* the members of the local group(s) to the collection(s) you specify.  You can add  domain groups (and/or local groups) to local groups on a workstation/server.  This ensures the defined collections are members of specified local groups *and* will *restrict* the addition of unapproved members to these local groups.

Comment: Be careful to note that using Restricted Groups will REPLACE the members of the current groups with the groups you specify. It will not ADD the members to the group in ADDITION to the current members.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Actually you can use Restricted Groups either in an  append *or* overwrite manner.  The *"Members of this group"* section will overwrite members, the *"This group is a member of"* section will append members.